# How to align text with the bottom of another object

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment, music

I have these chord-patterns and I want to add some text next to them. The problem is that it's aligned to the top. I feel like there should be an straight-forward way of aligning it to the bottom or the center (both would be fine by me).

To get it to the bottom I already tried messing around with: `\flushbottom`, `\raggedbottom`, `\vspace{}`, `\\[-1em]`, `\\topskip{}`

To get it centered I tried: `$\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}$`

Nothing worked. Help is much appreciated!

[image]

**Edit**: here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{guitarchordschemes} % how to put fingers on guitar
\usepackage{lipsum} % lorem ipsum dolor sit

% chord scheme setup
\setchordscheme{
    rotate = -90,
    name-below = true,
}

% specifications for a C chord
\newcommand{\CChord}{\chordscheme[%
    name = C,%
    finger = {1/2, 2/4, 3/5},%
    ring = {1, 3},
    mute = {6}]
}

\begin{document}
    \CChord \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

My complete chord scheme setup looks as follows. But I think that only the rotate parameter is relevant because for `rotate = 0` the text was bottom-aligned.

```
\setchordscheme{
    x-unit = 0.3cm,
    y-unit = 0.35cm,
    rotate = -90,
    finger-radius = 0.3,
    line-width = 0.2pt,
    strings = {6},
    tuning = {,,,,,},
    name-below = true,
    name-distance = 0.15em,
    name-format = \Large \bf,
    position-format = \normalsize,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE: what is the minimal working example? I.e. what is the code .tex that you must glue here?

Comment: In particular, please tell us how you insert the chord pattern images.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome!
I edited the question to include a minimal working example. 
I use the `guitarchordschemes` packacke to generate the chord patterns. It's a black box for me and I have no idea what happens internally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{guitarchordschemes} % how to put fingers on guitar
\usepackage{lipsum} % lorem ipsum dolor sit
\usepackage{adjustbox}

% chord scheme setup
\setchordscheme{
    rotate = -90,
    name-below = true,
}

% specifications for a C chord
\newcommand{\CChord}{\chordscheme[%
    name = C,%
    finger = {1/2, 2/4, 3/5},%
    ring = {1, 3},
    mute = {6}]
}

\begin{document}
    \adjustbox{valign=b}\CChord \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This works great! Thanks!
I just needed to add a `\noindent` inside the box, so that it aligns with the other pages.

Comment: @Gnaarf You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution using `\vspace` and `\hspace`. It's a hard-coded, magic-numbers solution, so it's not very elegant. But it gets the job done.

```
    \CChord 
    
    \vspace*{-1.1em}\hspace*{11.5em}{(Capo 2nd fret)}
    
    \subsubsection*{Verse 1} 
    Songtext, songtext, songtext \\
    Songtext, songtext, songtext \\
```

The empty line between `\CChord` and `\vspace(...)` is strictly necessary!